# Sqoop action using Oozie in Hue

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, oozie, sqoop

I am using AWS EMR and I am unable to submit Sqoop action through Oozie in Hue.I have installed sqoop and can run a sqoop job from cli and not through Oozie action in Hue.

The error that I get is "sqoop command not found"

Can anyone help me out with this?

Thank you.
Bharath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the oozie.use.system.libpath property equal to true

Answer (score 0):

In oozie on yarn model , you can try setting sqoop client in each node which yarn scheduled;
Cause of that yarn might send your sqoop workflow to the node which does not have sqoop client;